# An Application of Urysohn Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> Let $X$ metric space, $K\subset X$ compact and $f:K\to\mathbb R$ C-Lipschitz. Prove that there exisit $\hat{f}:X\to \mathbb R$ extension C-Lipschitz of $f$.

I have approximated "f" using a sequence $f_n$ give by compact hypothesis and Urysohn Lemma but I don't know how proceed.

Comment: See Pelcynski' classic paper *on simultaneous extensions of continuous functions* (Studia Math. 24 (1964), 286-304.